# the function about real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Could someone help me to do this hard problem?I'd appreciate it!

Prove that if f(x) is continuous and one-to-one on the closed interval [a, b], then f(x) is stictly monotone on [a, b]. (Recall that strictly monotone on [a, b] means that either for all x and y such that x ∈ [a, b], y ∈ [a, b] and x < y, we have f(x) < f(y), or for all x and y such that x ∈ [a, b], y ∈ [a, b] and x < y, we have f(x) > f(y).)

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26585/applications-of-connectedness/26619#26619

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose it is not (this is probably the hardest part, negating the statement "$f$ is monotone").

Then, use the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 0):

$f(a) \ne f(b)$ because the function is one-to-one.

Case 1:  Assume $f(a) < f(b)$.

Let $a < x < y < b$.  If $f(x) \le f(a) < f(b)$ then by the intermediate value theorem there is a $x: x < c < b$ so that $f(c) = f(a)$.  That's impossible because $f$ is 1-1. So $f(a) < f(x)$ and....

... can you finish this?...

If not, I'll come back and type some more in a few hours after dinner.

Comment: Thanks for your help.But I need your help for the rest of case, Thank you!

Comment: Well, prove f (x) < f (y) < f (b) the exact same to prove f is monotonically increaseing.  Show that if f (a) > f (b) it is monotonically decreasing for the exact same reason.